# How to validate property to be unique?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Code :

```
public class MyRepository
{
    public TeamContext _teamContext;

    public MyRepository(TeamContext teamContext)
    {
        _teamContext = teamContext;
    }

    public void AddTeam(Team team)
    {
        team.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _teamContext.Team.Add(team);
    }
}
```

Team names should be unique. Using Entity Framework how to validate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is another record with the *same name*. If yes, then you need to throw an exception. Otherwise, continue the flow.

```
public void AddTeam(Team team)
{  
    if(_textContext.Team.Any(t => t.Name == team.Name))
    {
        throw new TeamAlreadyExists(team.Name);
    }
    team.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    _teamContext.Team.Add(team);
}
```

I suggest you to do the check from an upper level, like *services*, to keep the repository's method as clean as possible.

Addition to this, it is recommended to use *unique constraint* on the database side as well, since it's thread-safe and it protects from editing team's name from other places.

Comment: While in some cases this is a valid solution, it's worth mentioning that using a unique constraint on the database side is the preferred solution, as it's both thread-safe and also protects from editing the team's name even from outside the software.

Answer (score 1):

use `UNIQUE` constraint that ensures all values in a column or a group of columns are distinct from one another or unique.
for example :

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

if you insert duplicate value in email,you get an error as follow:

```
Error while executing SQL query on database 'xxx': UNIQUE constraint failed: contacts.email
```

also you can set multi column unique:

```
CREATE TABLE tbaleName(
   ...
    UNIQUE(columnName_1,columnName_2)
   ...
);
```

**Notic:**
You cannot add a constraint to an existing table in sqlite. You can only rename table or add columns to a table.